# PHP Security for high traffic websites

Tags: php, security

How can a website build in PHP (like Facebook) can be so fast and (sorry if I'm wrong) secure ?

Do they use their own compiled version ? What kind special techniques do you guys think they use?

What config do we need to have to make PHP viable for huge scale project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should I be aware of to make my web application secure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720773/what-should-i-be-aware-of-to-make-my-web-application-secure)

Comment: HipHop is used to translate their PHP code to C++ which is then compiled. The performance gain reduces the number of servers they need.

Comment: The solutions I see from that post are the usual "To Do". I still believe Facebook must use advanced techniques. And protecting a website for SQL Injection wont make it viable for high-traffic website.

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware of that technique. What kind of server can run C++ code to answer HTTP requests?

Comment: Being fast and being secure are two completely unrelated matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That have a PHP compiler that transforms PHP into C++ (Hip-Hop), this is one big improvement. They also have written there entire backend in C++ (transport data through Apache Thrift) and built Cassandra.

I don't think their PHP necessarily has any specific security tools (or I haven't any seen any of them). Speaking for experience with Thrift, it helps when both frontend/backend understand exploits and both work to ensure there are no issues.

All of these things have helped alot, check our [High Scalability](http://highscalability.com/) for more information about scaling your stack

Comment: even large companies like Twitter are caught by things like xss attacks. having a team dedicated to security ensure issues like this don't happen help as well.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a question born of the stigma that has stuck to PHP that it is some how inherently insecure. PHP is flexible which allows developers to write bad, insecure code if that's all they know how to do.

Many, many large website and web apps are written in PHP. The key is knowing how to write code securely from the ground up. I'm sure Facebook has hired talented programmers who are trained on security.

Bad or insecure code is the fault of the programmer, not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend reading: [What should a developer know before building a public web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site)?